# Making web service calls on the same connection

Tags: java, web-services, http, apache-axis

I'm working on a WSDL-based web service and using Apache Axis 2.  I'm not an expert on web services, and the person I'm working with claims that in order for this particular web service to work two calls have to be made on the same connection, i.e. using http keep-alive (There's basically a "commit transaction" method that needs to be called after the "save" method). This seems like it would be a pretty common issue, but I haven't found anything on Google.

I'm wondering if there's a way to explicitly tell Axis to do this.  Also, how could I verify whether or not two calls are indeed being made on the same connection.  I imagine some HTTP monitoring software like wireshark might be able to tell me this, but I haven't installed it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person you are working with is wrong. Even if HTTP can be optimized by using keep-alive to process multiple requests over a single TCP connection, this optimization should be transparent to the caller or callee, e.g. it should not matter if a client make two requests after each other on a keep-alive connection or if it's using two separate connections.

Java libraries (HttpURLConnection on the client side and the servlet API on the server side) do not even offer access to this information, so that the using software cannot know how the HTTP requests are actually performed.

Comment: The only remaining question I have is if there's a commit transaction method that doesn't take any parameters, how does the server know the transaction?  Do web services/Axis include some session tracking mechanism, like a unique session id that gets passed along with each request?  Otherwise the people who created the web service I'm using had no idea what they were doing, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap[link text](http://nmap.org/) to see what is actually running on each port.

But if you are making 2 calls at same time, axis2 will throw port is already binded error. Any port can't handle 2 requests at the same time (my opinion). Maybe you can queue it and do it consecutively. But just confirm with other sources as well.